# AngularJs multiple Controllers, ng-click and ng-view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

This might be me just missing something or getting the wrong end of the stick on the tutorial, so bear with me.

I have my app....

```
var shepApp = angular.module('shepApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'ui-notification',
  'shepControllers',
  'shepFilters',
  'shepServices'
]);

shepApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/galaxies', {
        templateUrl: "partials/galaxies.html",
        controller: 'GalaxyListCtrl'
      }).
  }]);
```

And my controllers go something like this....

```
var shepControllers = angular.module('shepControllers', []);

shepControllers.controller('GalaxyListCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'Notification', 'Galaxy', function($scope, $location, Notification, Galaxy) {
  $scope.galaxys = Galaxy.query();
  $scope.blah = function(){
        alert(123);
  }
}]);

shepControllers.controller('GalaxyDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$location', 'Notification', 'Galaxy', function($scope, $routeParams, $location, Notification, Galaxy) {
  $scope.galaxy = Galaxy.get({slug: $routeParams.slug});
}]);
```

My `galaxies.html` partial contains the following HTML using `ng-click`.

```
<button ng-click="blah"></button>
```

My thinking was that that `blah` function for the click event would be exposed when my route is `/galaxies` and the controller in use is `GalaxyListCtrl` - but the alert is never fired at all.

I think I am missing something in the way this all fits together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling a function without arguments is done using the name of the function followed by parentheses:

```
ng-click="blah()"
```

Comment: Boom. Thanks. I knew it would be something simple!